# Quicksight Cascading filter

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a sheet that has several visuals and is managed by order_day level, among them I have one visual that shows total orders on hourly basis and has metro_region as control panel which shows all the metro regions irrespective the metro region has orders or no orders for that order day.
But I want a cascading filter when a particular region doesn’t have orders for that order_day it shouldn’t even show in the metro_region panel.

Not sure if cascading is the right way, I am new to Quicksight

I tried so many ways but couldn’t figure it out. Any help would be great.